# Calling boolean function without an argument inside of an if-statement in C++

Tags: c++, function

I was wondering, why is there no error when the block of code below is executed? The error should come from the `func1` block, because we are calling `func2` without an argument. What is being passed in the argument to `func2`?

I also realized this only happens when `func2` is a boolean function, and if it is called inside an `if` statement. I know that `"-4"` is not passed from the main function, because the output is `"1"` when it should be `"0"`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

bool func2(int b) 
{
  return b>0;
}

int func1(int a) 
{
  if (func2) return 1;
  else return 0;
}

int main() 
{
  std::cout << func1(-4);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not calling `func2`. (Note the missing parentheses).

Comment: Then what is being called with "func2"? Why is there no error saying that "func2" is not defined?

Comment: `if (func2(a))`

Comment: I know that I should be using parentheses to call a function. But when you write the code like this, it executes with no errors. That is what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: `func2` in `if (func2)` is a function pointer, which can be converted to `bool`. Anything other than `nullptr` (which is the case here) will evaluate `true`.

Comment: A function name that is not followed by parentheses is a *pointer* (to that function). You are testing whether or not that pointer is null (which it really can't be).

Comment: I see now, I wasn't aware of this in C++. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note: if you turn on warnings, your compiler would have likely warned you about this: `warning: the address of 'bool func2(int)' will never be NULL [-Waddress]` https://godbolt.org/z/P78Tzqj91

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the code doesn't fail to compile is because of function-to-function-pointer decay.

When you use just the name of a function, it will decay into a pointer to that function.  The pointer can then be converted to a `bool` that will be `true` if the pointer points to something, and `false` if it is a `null` pointer.

Since the pointer is pointing to a function, it will have a non-null value, and that means the expression will evaluate to `true`.